# nodeJS method giving error even after the JSON data is persisted on MongoDB

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, express

I am new to nodeJS and mongoDB. Creating an application using nodeJS as the middleware, mongoDB as the Database and angularJS in the UI.

In nodeJS having controller and the model to the business logic as well as to persist the data. Currently the issue is in the controller getting error even after the object is inserted the DB(from the model).

Controller code is as below:

```
router.post("/add", function(req,res){
var student = req.body;
Students.add(student, function(err) {
if (err) {
  throw err;
}
var respOut = JSON.stringify({id:student.id});
console.log("respOut");
res.send(respOut);
});
});
```

Model code :

```
exports.add = function(student, cb) {
var collection = db.get().collection('students');
collection.insert(student, function(err) {
if (err) {
   throw err;
}
console.log("Record added");
});
}
```

In the UI side uses the below angularJS code to submit the data to the nodeJS controller:

```
mainApp.controller("addStudentController", function($scope,$http) {
var resData = {};
$scope.output = "";
var url = "/students/add";
$scope.addStudent = function(){
    $http.post(url, $scope.student)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        resData = angular.fromJson(data);
        $scope.output = "Student entered successfully with unique Id "+resData.id;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        resStatus = status;
        $scope.output = "Something went wrong. Please try again later."
    });
}
});
```

Please help!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

once check it out in controller whether it is `student._id` because node by default creates the id with "`_`" as prefix